# WampServer and error 404

Tags: php, php.ini, phpmyadmin

Having just installed Wampserver on my system in order to test a PHP form I have created via Dreamweaver, I'm continually getting the Error 404 message on my screen despite following the installation instructions to the letter.

My OS is Windows 10 64x
My WAMP Server version is 3.3.0
I have the C++ Visual files 2015 - 2022

I cannot even get the PHPAdmin up on the screen. Created a helloworld.php document, ran 'http://localhost/test/helloworld.php'and I still get the same result.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

**Detailed Error Information:**
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/test/helloworld.php
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\helloworld.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Comment: You are connecting to IIS, not Apache.

Comment: Thanks, get it sorted, just had to restart the system.